# Visual Studio Publish profile settings for Single Page App on Azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, vue.js, azure-web-app-service

I want to publish my single page app to Azure. I have created the App Service, App Service Plan and downloaded the publish profile settings on my local. Now I can use FTP to publish it to Azure. But I am wondering if there is a way I can configure this in the my Visual Studio similar to what we do when publishing a .Net application (MVC or Web API) as shown below in the snapshot.

[image]

My single page application is not part of the solution. This is how the structure of my projects look like.

[image]

It has one .Net Core Web API project and one Single Page App created in Vue.js. I can publish the Web API project from the Visual Studio but not the SPA. Any help with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, it is impossible to publish it in Visual Studio similar to what we do when publishing a .Net application. There is no `Publish...` option for us to choose.

As a workaround, we can upload our SPA project to Azure web app via KuDu.

More information about KuDu, we can refer to: [Using KUDU with Microsoft Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)

We just need to drag the SPA project into KUDU under wwwroot folder as below:

[image]